# Git Refresh Merge Points Both Branches to Most Recent Commit

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

My team is using Bitbucket with 'msysgit' and Eclipse's git plugin in Windows to manage out git repo. We typically have a master and 2 or 3 feature branches that can be based off each other. We came across a case where after we refresh 'feature-2' from 'feature-1' both 'feature-1' and 'feature-2' point to the merged commit. This pollutes 'feature-1' with commits that should not be in 'feature-1'. Please see the diagram below.

```
feature-1   --0--1--\--2--3--4--\
                     \ create    \ refresh
feature-2             \--5--6--7--\---
```

'feature-1' is in existence. 'feature-2' is created and worked on while 'feature-1' is worked on. A merge is done from 'feature-1' to 'feature-2'.

```
git checkout feature-2
git merge feature-1
git push
```

Now 'feature-1' and 'feature-2' point to the same commit hash and 'feature-1' contains the commits from 'feature-2'.

Sometimes this workflow behaves as I expect it to, where 'feature-2' contains all commits from 'feature-1' and 'feature-1' stays at its own head. Sporadically, we experience what I am reporting.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? I feel like I am missing some rudimentary concept.

Answer (score 1):

The only way this:

```
git checkout feature-2
git merge feature-1
```

will end up with `feature-1` and `feature-2` both pointing at the same commit is if `feature-2` did not have any commits on it since it was either branched off `feature-1` or since the last merge - this will result in a fast-forward merge which just moves the pointer for `feature-2` to point to the same commit as `feature-1`. Even if that is the case, future commits on the two branches will diverge again, as they are still separate pointers, even though they point to the same thing for a time.

Once you have done a merge, it's normal for the merged-into-branch (`feature-2` in this case) to appear to have all the `feature-1` commits up to the merge point in it's history - that's what you wanted. `feature-1` should not show the commits from `feature-2` unless someone inadvertently did the opposite merge (e.g. `git checkout feature-1; git merge feature-2`). You should be able to visualize what is going in with `gitk --all`.